Reinstalling MikTeX

yesterday I was working on a project using latex on VSCode when suddenly the compiling process stopped working, as in the compiling process started but wouldnt end (neither by error or sucess).
So I opened the MikTeX console, switched to admin mode and checked for updates, and auto-updated all. After the update the console closed itself, but when I attempted to open it again I got an error saying "this application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized".
Then I attempted to reinstall, but suprisingly to me, even when I attempted to uninstall it using the Windows apps, I got the same error, thus I cannot even reinstall MikTeX console.
So I opened cmd and typed "miktex packages verify" which gave me that "miktex-qt6-bin-x64: this package needs to be reinstalled", thus I also typed miktex --admin packages update, but this only told me that the package database is locked and cannot be accessed and that an another MikTeX program has exclusively locked the database (I dont exactly know which one and how to close it).
And so I am asking for advice as though how to proceed. My project is due today and so I am asking for help with this issue, as I am a beginner with Latex and dont know how to proceed.

In case you don't manage to get miktex working again, you could try texlive instead of miktex: https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html

If under time pressure, you could also try and see if your project compiles on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/ and figure out the problems on your computer later.

You can install the missing package on the command line. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1486#issuecomment-2084843465

I had a similar problem a few months ago.  Instead of uninstalling MikTeX, I deleted the entire MikTeX folder in program files (or in my case C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs)/  Then I reinstalled it from the web site,  Note that you wil also have to reinstall all your packages and documentation.  BTW, AppData is a hidden folder.
